# Get media files and display in the list

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a beginner in android. According to following the document 'Access media files from shared storage'. I want to display name all audio in the list, but it only shows one audio. Could someone help me to solve this? Thanks. Here my code.`

```
    ArrayList<audio> arrayList = new ArrayList<audio>();
    String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE
    };
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION +
            " >= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    try (Cursor cursor = v.getContext().getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
    )) {

        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int durationColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
        int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
            int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);

            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

            // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
            // that represents the media file.
            arrayList.add(new audio(name));
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Dont use selection and selectionArgs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realized that change selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION  to  DISPLAY_NAME